# Get difference of time and output to decimal format

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to get the different between two times, lets say 2:00PM and 12:00AM. So I want to get how many hours are between those two times but have it be in decimal format which in this case would be 10.00 hours?. I am not sure how to go about this. The most I got to was just subtracting the two times and multiplying that decimal number by 24 which works if I do 2PM and 11PM which gives me 9.00hours, but as soon as I go to 2PM and 12AM it should show 10.00hours but shows -14.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your times are in ColumnA ("earlier") and ColumnB ("later") then:

```
=if(B1=0,(B1-A1+1)*24,(B1-A1)*24)
```

should work for you. The quotes are because (seems to depend upon how the times values are entered) Google may associate a date with the times even when that is not displayed. Google treats noon as `12:00PM` which is wrong, it is noon not *after* noon (post meridiem) but one minute later `12:01PM`, etc, does make sense. So `12:00AM` is midnight and a special case where a date is associated because seen as midnight of the previous day - it counts as `0` not `24`. Hence relative to 2pm today is 14 hours earlier (your result) whereas midnight tonight is 10 ahead (the result you expected).

The formula above checks whether the later *time* is midnight and compensates for that being treated as the day before by `+1` in the formula.